# Orthogonality in the Tight-binding model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, tight-binding

In the linear combination of atomic orbitals and the Tight-binding model we write the wave functions for some **k** as a linear combination of Bloch states like this

$$
\Psi_n(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k}) = \sum_{\textbf{R}}e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{R}}\psi_n(\textbf{r}-\textbf{R})
$$

Where, $\psi_n(\textbf{r}-\textbf{R})$ is the n-th atomic wave function. Now in a lattice, these atomic orbitals are localized on the atomic sites, but they overlap also to some extent with each other. My question is simple and short, but very important and could leave a gap in understanding the model if it's not discussed properly.

Is it a condition to write the sum above, that these $\psi_n(\textbf{r}-\textbf{R})$ belonging to different sites should be orthogonal on each other?
**In other words, is there an orthogonality condition that defines the validity of the sum written above?**

Answer (score 0):

> In the linear combination of atomic orbitals and the Tight-binding model we write the wave functions for some **k** as a linear combination of Bloch states like this
> $$
> \Psi_n(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k}) = \sum_{\textbf{R}}e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{R}}\psi_n(\textbf{r}-\textbf{R})
> $$
> Where, $\psi_n(\textbf{r}-\textbf{R})$ is the n-th atomic wave function....

> Is it a condition to write the sum above, that these $\psi_n(\textbf{r}-\textbf{R})$ belonging to different sites should be orthogonal on each other?

No. Atomic orbitals at the *same* site but of *different* $n$ can be taken orthogonal, but atomic orbitals centered at different sites are not orthogonal (although physically we understand that the overlap is "small" when the binding is "tight.")

If you want strictly orthogonal spatial functions associated with lattice points $\vec R$, then you should use [Wannier functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannier_function) instead of atomic orbitals.

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying that we assume that the overlap is small and negligible, and in this way, we can safely write this sum. But in strict cases, dealing with the non-orthogonality of orbitals on different sites is required. What about using Löwdin's prescription to construct orthogonal sums, if you heard of it?

Comment: You often use a sum like the one you wrote to *approximate* a Bloch wave function. The major approximation will often come from truncating the sum over $n$ at a very low $n_{max}$in order to achieve some expression that is numerically tractable. You can always *write* the sum, but it is not always useful. You will expect to truncate the sum over orbitals since otherwise you have an over-complete set of functions. Whether or not something is "strict" is vague, so I don't know how to answer. If you want "strictly" orthogonal wavefunctions associated with a lattice site use Wannier functions.

Comment: In practice (e.g., numerical calculations IRL) you would likely not use Wannier functions for numerical calculations since they are just as hard to obtain as Bloch functions. But for theoretical calculations sometimes Wannier functions are useful.

Comment: In practice, to actually do numerical calculations, you could also truncate the sum over lattice sites, e.g., restrict yourself to a "cluster" of atoms around some central atom of interest (e.g., an atom that absorbed an x-ray or whatever).